# Unzip a specific subfolder in an archive with the 7-Zip command line version

Tags: console, 7-zip

I want to unzip an [ZIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29) archive, but just a subfolder in it.

Example structure archive.zip:

```
-rootfolder
--subfolder
---subsubfolder
```

I just want to unzip **subsubfolder** with [7-Zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip) (preferably). How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

To unzip only the "doc" directory inside the ZIP file to "/tmp" directory, you need to specify the absolute path of "doc" directory inside ZIP file:

> [bash]$ unzip test.zip "test/doc/*" -d
>   /tmp/

Answer (score 1):

```
$ 7z x archive.zip rootfolder/subfolder
```

The syntaxes of all commands in 7-Zip are similar. `x` stands for "eXtract with full paths".

Answer (score -1):

Open the archive.zip with the 7-Zip file manager. Click and highlight the subfolder. Extract.
I'm not sure how to use the command line interface for this behavior.